# ClearOS 7 Allow non-root user to access IP Settings locally

Tags: networking, intranet, clearos

I need to provide several intranet servers that will work in several different places with basically the same configurations.

I installed ClearOS 7 on them and everything works as expected.

The problem is that each local network might require a different IP Configuration and I want an unprivileged user to be able to access this interface, so I do not have to provide them with root's password.

ClearOS has a good Graphics-mode Interface for managing IP Settings. This interface opens automatically on the first boot or on subsequent boots if I *login as root* and then choose to Open Graphics-mode Console.

I created a user using ClearOS7 Webconfig interface. This user can login in the IP Settings interface but this interface does not open by default.

How to make the Graphics-mode Console always appear after boot without requiring root's password?

Comment: I found a simillar question here: https://www.clearos.com/clearfoundation/social/community/re-enter-webconfig-from-terminal/oldest#filter-sort. But it also does not explain how to open it on boot always.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the process that starts the gconsole is a systemctl service, located on:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/gconsole.service
```

I enabled it with `systemctl enable gconsole`, but it failed to start on boot for some reason that I was not able to diagnose.

To circumvent this problem I added `Restart=always` to the `[service]` block of the `.service` file, i.e.:

```
[Unit]
Description='ClearOS Graphical Console'
After=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
User=clearconsole
Group=clearconsole
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startx
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=getty@tty1.service
```

Now if it fails on boot (and it always fails the first time) it will keep trying until it works.

It is not an elegant solution, but it solved it for me and I was unable to find any docs or questions referencing this issue that could point me to a better method.

### Starting gconsole from cli

Also if someone gets here looking for a simple way to start gconsole by cli use `start-gconsole` or `systemctl start gconsole`.

I hope it helps.